# Timer_EntityBody, Timer_ConnectionIdle and Connection Closed Unexpectly

Tags: windows-server-2008, http, iis-7.5, windows, web-services

We have a windows application, it connects to a web service (XML web service hosted on a Windows 2008 Server IIS 7.5, no antivirus) and fetches some data to the client. But sometimes (around 5%-10% of the requests), it gives an error when trying to connect web service.

Here is the client application error log;

```
Exception:System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientAsyncResult.WaitForResponse()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.EndSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object& internalAsyncState, Stream& responseStream)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at APPClient.APPFPService.WEBService.EndAddMoney(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at APPClient.BLL.ServiceAgent.AddMoneyCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

From other hand, on the web server, i checked HTTP error logs and i see a long file like this;

```
2014-06-05 14:02:04 65.82.178.73 53798 SERVER.IP.ADDRESS 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2014-06-05 14:07:24 76.109.81.223 58985 SERVER.IP.ADDRESS 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2014-06-05 14:07:39 76.109.81.223 2803 SERVER.IP.ADDRESS 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2014-06-05 14:08:59 76.109.81.223 52656 SERVER.IP.ADDRESS 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2014-06-05 14:09:05 65.82.178.73 53904 SERVER.IP.ADDRESS 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /webservice/webservice.asmx - 2 Timer_EntityBody SYPService
2014-06-05 14:10:55 50.186.180.191 50648 SERVER.IP.ADDRESS 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
```

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/186555/long-access-times-and-errors-in-iis-application) is a similar situation but it did not help me.

**UPDATE**:
When i checked the IIS logs, i see some issues like these;

```
cs-method   cs-uri-stem                     sc-status   sc-win32-status     time-taken  cs-version
POST        /webservice/webservice.asmx     400         64                  46          HTTP/1.1
POST        /webservice/webservice.asmx     400         64                  134675      HTTP/1.1
POST        /webservice/webservice.asmx     400         64                  37549       HTTP/1.1
POST        /webservice/webservice.asmx     400         64                  109         HTTP/1.1
POST        /webservice/webservice.asmx     400         64                  31          HTTP/1.1
POST        /webservice/webservice.asmx     400         64                  0           HTTP/1.1
POST        /webservice/webservice.asmx     400         64                  15          HTTP/1.1
```

[sc-win32-status 64](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.0&EvtID=64&EvtSrc=Kernel) : The specified network name is no longer available.

[sc-status 400](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891) : Bad request

Also some requests takes around 130 seconds, but some of less than 1 second. This is a windows application which connects to a web service for process some data. There is not a query takes around 130 seconds on the database.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the HTTPERR logs, but they might not be the whole story.

There's a reference for what each code means here: [820729](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820729) and in short, the only point of concern above is the POST which was disallowed for taking too long (Timer_EntityBody - i.e. the entity body was not received before the HTTPAPI-configured timeout from your app).

It's unclear whether you're hosting this app in IIS, but I'd suggest that if you're getting those errors, you investigate them at the app level (\inetpub\logs\w3svcxxx) rather than the system level (\windows\system32\logfiles\httperr).

The App logs are likely to contain any app-level errors, problems or burps, and there might also be evidence in the Application event log, in EventVwr.

Comment: Thanks @TristanK, I checked IIS logs and added some issues on the IIS logs. All issues like these samples. 

There is not an error on the Event viewer.

Comment: You need to debug your web service. You can use Failed Request Tracing to help identify what it thinks it's doing on long-running requests and/or any 400 errors.

Answer (score 0):

from the IIS log. it shows that the web service could not be reached or it not available "  /webservice/webservice.asmx     400  ". Run the web service separate to confirm if the web service is up and running in the same server where  the windows service is hosted. Also this could be a network issue if the windows service and the web service are in different location.

Answer (score 0):

400 status means “Bad Request”. So this is not a server-side issue. There is something wrong with the request. Is not well-formed before reaching to IIS

If the substatus code was something other than 0, it would be easier to troubleshoot. For example, If it was 1, it would mean “Invalid Destination Header”. If it was 2, that would mean “Invalid Depth Header”. Here is the [full list of status codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code).

64 in sc-win32-status there is a network-related issue. It refers to “The specified network name is no longer available”. After sending the response, IIS waits for ACK package from the client. If the client resets the connection instead of sending this package, IIS logs 64 code since it’s not a graceful connection close.

Timer_EntityBody error means “The connection expired before the request entity body arrived”.

**Recommendations**

- Check if there are software like antivirus or network endpoint
  protection in the server. Uninstall them and monitor the system for a
  while to see if the issue occurs again (Note: disabling them
  sometimes doesn't mean they don't run in the background anymore.
  Uninstalling is the ultimate way of eliminating them from the
  troubleshooting process)
- Work with the third-party product support to
  see if there is anything blocking the requests to be fully sent.
  Application might be initiating the connection but not completing it
- Check with your Networking team to analyze the network between the
  web server and client. Ideally, a network trace would be very helpful

Source: [Status Code 400 with 64 in sc-win32-status column](https://port135.com/status-code-400-64/)